# How to initialize a field with @Autowired annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to use @Autowired annotation to initialize a service bean in springboot, but some exceptions accur when the applitaion starting.
Here is the code.

```
package com.kindlepocket.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService;
import com.kindlepocket.web.util.CheckUtil;
import com.kindlepocket.web.util.MessageUtil;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/Weixin")
public class KindlePocketController {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Autowired
private TextBookInfoSearchService searchService;// = new TextBookInfoSearchService();

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KindlePocketController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/wx.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void validate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("signature") String signature, @RequestParam("timestamp") String timestamp,
        @RequestParam("nonce") String nonce, @RequestParam("echostr") String echostr) {

    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("\n***The message got: signature:" + signature + " timestamp:" + timestamp
                + " nonce:" + nonce + " echostr:" + echostr);
    }

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("response error");
        }
    }

    if (CheckUtil.checkSignature(signature, timestamp, nonce)) {
        out.print(echostr);
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("validated!");
        }
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/wx.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity processMessage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    /*
     * PrintWriter out = null; try { out = response.getWriter(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     */

    try {

        Map<String, String> map = MessageUtil.xmlToMap(request);
        String fromUserName = map.get("FromUserName");
        String toUserName = map.get("ToUserName");
        String msgType = map.get("MsgType");
        String content = map.get("Content");

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("\n***The message got: fromUserName:" + fromUserName + " toUserName:"
                    + toUserName + " msgType:" + msgType + " content:" + content);
        }

        String responseMessage = null;
        if (MessageUtil.MESSAGE_TEXT.equals(msgType)) {

            switch (content) {
            case "1":
                responseMessage = MessageUtil.initText(toUserName, fromUserName, MessageUtil.firstMenu());
                break;
            case "2":
                responseMessage = MessageUtil
                        .initText(toUserName, fromUserName, MessageUtil.secondMenu());
                break;
            case "3":
                responseMessage = MessageUtil.initPicTextMessage(toUserName, fromUserName);
                break;
            default:
                // responseMessage = MessageUtil.initText(toUserName, fromUserName, MessageUtil.menuText());
                List<String> titleList = this.searchService.search(content);
                responseMessage = MessageUtil.initPicTextMessage(toUserName, fromUserName, titleList);
                break;
            }

            /*
             * TextMessage textMessage = new TextMessage(); textMessage.setFromUserName(toUserName); textMessage.setToUserName(fromUserName); textMessage.setMsgType("text"); textMessage.setCreateTime(new Date().getTime()); textMessage.setContent("the message you sent was : " + content); responseMessage = MessageUtil.textMessageToXml(textMessage); if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) { logger.info("the message responsed is :\n" + responseMessage); }
             */
        } else if (MessageUtil.MESSAGE_EVENT.equals(msgType)) {
            String eventType = map.get("Event");
            if (MessageUtil.MESSAGE_SUBSCRIBE.equals(eventType)) {
                responseMessage = MessageUtil.initText(toUserName, fromUserName,
                        MessageUtil.welcomeText());
            }
        }
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("\n***The message responsed: \n" + responseMessage);
        }
        // out.print(responseMessage);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(responseMessage);

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    } /*
       * finally { out.close(); }
       */

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(KindlePocketController.class, args);
}
```

}

And following is service.

```
package com.kindlepocket.web.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TextBookInfoSearchService {

private ApiService apiService = new ApiService();

public List<String> search(String content) {

    Map<String, Object> contentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    contentMap.put("title", content);
    try {
        String result = this.apiService.doGet("http://127.0.0.1:8081/search/title", contentMap);
        System.out.println("result:" + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    // test
    titles.add("张学良口述历史");
    titles.add("布谷鸟的呼唤");
    return titles;

}
```

}

And here is the log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kindlePocketController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService com.kindlepocket.web.controller.KindlePocketController.searchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at com.kindlepocket.web.controller.KindlePocketController.main(KindlePocketController.java:140) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService com.kindlepocket.web.controller.KindlePocketController.searchService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.kindlepocket.web.service.TextBookInfoSearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted

2016-04-24 22:08:34.805  INFO 16680 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/E:/git_Repo/kindlePocketRepoMine/kindlepocket-web/target/classes/, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.4c/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/4.10.2/solr-solrj-4.10.2.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.1/httpmime-4.5.1.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.7/wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/noggit/noggit/0.5/noggit-0.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.5/httpclient-4.3.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/E:/itcast-workspace/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar]
```

And pom.xml follows:
    `    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0
       com.kindlepocket.web
       kindlepocket-web
       0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

`
I don't know why the injection failed.
Did I missed some configurations ? Or the annotation is not correct?
Thanks everyone .

Comment: Did you set the <context:component-scan base-package="com.kindlepocket" /> in spring's configuration?

Comment: @PacoAbato oh I didn't, I thought spring boot will not need this configuration. Is that also a necessary configuration in springboot?  thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. Try it anyway.

Comment: @PacoAbato that's not necessary in Spring Boot.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but you should consider using constructor injection instead of field injection for better design and better testability. Please see this article by Oliver Gierke: [Why field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)

Comment: @Kiview thanks a lot, I'll take care of this

Answer (score 0):

What I see as a problem here is that you have added `@Component` to class `TextBookInfoSearchServiceq`. But you are referring it as `searchService` in `KindlePocketController`. Spring will look for a bean with id `searchService` of given type. So, you need to annotate `TextBookInfoSearchServiceq` with `@Component("searchService")` or rename variable in `KindlePocketController` as `textBookInfoSearchServiceq`.

Comment: That should not be necessary cause spring boot by default is binding by type – as you can also see from the log file. So binding by name is something that can be helpful if you have multiple implementations of the same type but is not necessary when only one implementation does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your setting of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your Controller class cause this is located in `com.kindlepocket.web.controller` and will therefore only look for other beans in this and sub packages. But your `TextBookInfoSearchService` is located in `com.kindlepocket.web.service` and will not be resolved automatically.

Ideally you move your `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to a class on the root level of your application. Assuming the common denominator of your classes is `com.kindlepocket.web` what I wood do is to place there a Application.java that does not contain more than a main method to create the context and is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which includes `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried to move main function in the root location with the annotation @SpringBootApplication and service is in the sub package, but the same exception log occured...I don't know what do I missed. Thanks again.

Comment: How does your Application class look? I'm pretty sure your service does not get properly instantiated.

Comment: `package com.kindlepocket.web;

  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

  import com.kindlepocket.web.controller.KindlePocketController;

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(KindlePocketController.class, args);
      }

  }`

Comment: Do you still have the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your RestController?

Comment: Oh my mistake , I forgot it. And now I removed @EnableAutoConfiguration  on the controller and the main function , the log shows following：`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.`

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.`

Comment: hi guy, could you please help me to fix this issue? I tried to find the problem but failed. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Can you share your project somewhere? Maybe on github?

Comment: This is my project:    
https://github.com/pocketContributor/kindlePocket.git
thanks a lot

Comment: I just had a look. In essence I'd suggest that you always should try to work with the framework and not against it. Spring-Boot has an opinion how to do things and where to put stuff. You can change it but the defaults are already quite a good point to start from. I'm working on your code and will fork and pull-request my changes when I get it to work.

Comment: @nasuf: sorry to say but the project is really weird. I wasn't able to get it working changing things but started the other way around and used start.spring.io to create a scaffold. I could render it down to the dom4j dependency which is causing an issue. But I'd strongly suggest you start over and do it like it is intended, e.g.: static content belongs into /resources/static and you should but a application.properties in your resources. And instead of using HttpClient directly go for RestTemplate and define the DTOs with annotations and not doing that by hand.

Comment: thanks anyway, I'll try to find out the reason and update here.:)